# The fastest way to UPDATE multiple rows in C# ADO .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I'm trying to improve this query perfromance. I have to update multiple rows in once and this take too long for me. For example 4k rows for update takes 15 seconds.

My code:

```
using (var db = new DbConnection())
{
    int counter = 0;

    foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
    {
        if (!db.IsTransactionOpen)
        { 
            db.OpenTransaction();
        }

        DbQuery q = db.CreateQuery();

        q += "UPDATE Product SET Name = @Name WHERE Id = @Id";
        q.AddParameter("@Name", item.Name);
        q.AddParameter("@Id", item.Id);

        db.ExecuteQuery();
        counter++;

        if (counter > 100)
        {
            db.CommintTransaction();
        }
    }

    if (!db.IsTransactionOpen)
    { 
        db.CommintTransaction();
    }
}
```

I'm not satisfied with that update time. There is any way to speed up this? I used simplified update query in example, I tested without transaction and it takes much more time.

Comment: As above, without the where you are updating every record in the table for every loop you are doing.  If you have 1000 rows in the table, and you are looping 100 times, you are making 100000 updates in your code, instead of just 100.

Comment: Maybe make a stored procedure in sql. The stored procedure can perform the update and create c# code that calls that stored procedure with the same parameters and do a fire and forget call to the stored procedure. This will work if you do not need to await the result of the stored procedure. Calling the C# method and not awaiting a response would make it faster, but not guarantee the update was successful.

Comment: Batching commands into transactions is a performance optimization that prevents the need to flush the log file after each command.

Comment: Convert your items data to json and then join the table against openjsoned values, can't beat that in simplicity or speed unless you have millions of rows

Comment: https://kagawacode.medium.com/speed-benchmark-for-sql-bulk-insert-update-temp-table-vs-table-valued-parameters-3439b943d27c

This little blog post explains various methods pretty well, and has good examples.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to send the data in JSON and join it in a single SQL statement, eg with a nvarchar(max) parameter set to

```
[{"id":1,"name":"a"},{"id":2,"name":"b"},{"id":4,"name":"c"}]
```

run

```
with newValues as
(
  select * from openjson(@json) with (id int, name nvarchar(200))
),
q as
(
  select p.Name, p.Id, n.name NewName
  from Product p
  join  newValues n
    on p.id = n.id
)
update q set Name = NewName
```

Comment: This is fine, but why not just do a straight join between Product and OPENJSON?

Comment: I don't get it how to do it :D

Comment: Why `openjson` and not a TVP?

Comment: wow that slick, is you have short list. otherwise can be TVP as parameter...

Comment: @siggemannen UPDATE … FROM is non-standard, and confuses me.

Comment: @DaleK TVP is good too, but you have to create the type ahead-of-time.  And JSON is easy and OPENJSON is pretty fast.

Comment: as other approach i did for thousands records: bulk load in to working table and call sp to update joined on source table

Comment: Yep.  Here's my checkdown of loading methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498577/most-performant-way-to-insert-thousands-of-rows-of-data-into-azure-sql-db/71499452#71499452

Answer (score 2):

You should  use a Table Valued Parameter.

First create a Table Type

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.IdString (Id bigint PRIMARY KEY, Value varchar(500));
```

Then you can do

```cs
var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
    { "Id", typeof(long) },
    { "Value", typeof(string) },
} };

foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
    table.Add(item.Id, item.Name);

using var db = new DbConnection();
const string query = @"
UPDATE p
SET Name = i.Value
FROM Product p
JOIN @items i ON i.Id = p.Id;
";

DbQuery q = db.CreateQuery();
q += query;

p = q.AddParameter("@items", SqlDbType.Structured);
p.Value = table;
p.TypeName = "dbo.IdString";

db.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve the performance of your SQL update operation, you can consider using a batch update approach rather than updating each row individually. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
using (var db = new DbConnection())
{
    
    db.OpenTransaction();

    foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
    {
        DbQuery q = db.CreateQuery();

        q += "UPDATE Product SET Name = @Name WHERE Id = @Id";
        q.AddParameter("@Name", item.Name);
        q.AddParameter("@Id", item.Id);
        
        db.AddQueryToBatch(q);

        counter++;

        if (counter % 1000 == 0)
        {
            // Execute the batch and clear it every 1000 queries
            db.ExecuteBatch();
        }
    }
    db.ExecuteBatch();
    db.CommitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: That will still be executing one statement per update (which is slow), it's just sending a bunch together over the network.

Comment: But it won't be waiting for confirmation of each update before starting the next one, which can be a major time saver.